# How to get the types of props sent to a function when the arguments are different for each case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've got a component that has most of the logic for a particular task.

That component has to call the onSubmit function that it's getting through the props based on the component that it's been called form.

This is a sample code of the component having the logic:

```
type ComponentTwoProps = {
  onSubmit: () => void
}

const ComponentTwo: React.FC<ComponentTwoProps> = ({onSubmit}) => {

const firstName = 'John';
const lastName = 'Doe';
const email = 'johndoe@gmail.com';
const country = 'Germany';

switch (type) {
  case 'component-one':
    onSubmit(firstName, lastName);
    break;
  case 'component-two':
    onSubmit(firstName, lastName, email);
    break;
  case 'component-three':
    onSubmit(firstName, lastName, email, country);
    break;
  default:
}

  return (
    //code
  )
}

export default ComponentTwo
```

Now I have multiple components (three in this example) that will pass the onSubmit to this component as shown:

```
import React from 'react';
import ComponentTwo from './ComponentTwo';

const ComponentOne: React.FC = () => {
  const onClickHandler = (...props) => {
    //does stuff based on props FOR COMPONENT ONE
    //NEEDS ACCESS TO THE TYPE OF PROPS
  };

  return <ComponentTwo onClick={onClickHandler} />;
};

export default ComponentOne;
```

In my actual case the amount of parameters and their types vary greatly. So i wanted to know if there's a way I could access those types inside onClickHandler function.

I was thinking of using generics in some way but cant come up with a solution that supports any number of arguments and those arguments collectively have a unique type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you know that the arguments are always going to be strings

```
import React from 'react';

type ComponentTwoProps = {
  onSubmit: <T extends string>(...props: T[]) => void
}

const ComponentTwo: React.FC<ComponentTwoProps> = ({onSubmit}) => {

const firstName = 'John';
const lastName = 'Doe';
const email = 'johndoe@gmail.com';
const country = 'Germany';

  return (
    <></>
  )
}



const ComponentOne: React.FC = () => {
  const onClickHandler = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => {
    //does stuff based on props FOR COMPONENT ONE
    //NEEDS ACCESS TO THE TYPE OF PROPS
  };

  return <ComponentTwo onSubmit={onClickHandler} />;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGFdIA7JFmAFQHcIAFHGADOcALxwA3uThwILAMoBXAEYhgMAFxwAPJzhIAHjHYATEUJhRgLAOYA+ABQA6F2EFCtnANoBdAJRidnAAbhDAJuQAvpRochaMzHLsXLxayOgwTgBiDNpM4EkcPPzuQeIOEnJKquqRAaJBUuSxLPGYwFAWAHIoIPTi+ABSEAAWLGTNcfAANijdvf0EACIQSBMt8UggKMDTYgQAVqMsJqsAAjbbu06xIOtTcLGKHFDU+-gA4khQ2yzUE+QAPSAuBCbjqNAjOAOGh0AJSYEyR5zej4W6sZIAWiS+A0QJBSNkChUahgDnanRgPT6ABo4LN5n0-BREYTlEQUABrFkE5FCVHowowTEwXi4-GEonVUnkjqMpB0hlUhZ0rY7abMiVsjncrV8gWJNgcEUjIhrPGspFVEnqWWU6kK+lzZW0-RXaZ0p4vaiay0ydmoXWWkxITAoRTTTQS6LSOBEGCKKAsaGxmTaOzaQF2WN+KKUGIPfIYjgAeTYaWImRy+wc9UasY28DkDGmwDQnIAEigTtNvjWKfKtBYrLZFc6HUPLNYbHXJKm4MDTkhzAnMJg4MoUSYiXA3BBhHAsiWEIwSwBZPglroAUS6eiv1-nwJv16W8jgAEEGAxr-J35wSzgTgO2vICAE0+FAkssjgPgEBLPh5FjSIKFjeNE2TPJDWSYopRtGBREqFgWzbTtuxMXsoEiBc7AoFCgA)

Comment: There could be at least 3-5 different types. What are my options in that case?

Comment: you can use `any[]`, but then you lose type checking